# How to display value from updated table in dropdown list in ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, web, visual-studio-2017

I am not able to successfully display the current value from a SQL Server database table after I have successfully updated the table from a dropdownlist in ASP.NET.

My dropdownlist works, I can select a value and it updates in the table. When I click the save button, it does show my values as saved on the `.aspx` page. However, the value does not display in the dropdown when I later display that `.aspx` page.

I will mention that my dropdown list is from a select of 2 values concatenated together, but my update to the table is the primary key, to retain db normalization. If this is what is causing the unwanted behavior, can anyone provide advice on how to display the value after update? It does work for any fields where I am not using concatenated values on the dropdownlists.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, selecting a value in a dropdown does not "updates" the table - so that's confusing.

We assume that in most cases the drop down has two values. The PK value from the list (value), and then the display column. As noted, you might concentrate text + values or whatever for this 2nd column, but it still going to return the ID value which you save in the database - right? So we really don't care what expression or what you have for that 2nd column, but the first column has to be the PK id.

so say we select a Hotel. We could include the "city" in that hotel name list like this:

```
        <h3>Select Hotel</h3>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotel2" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="MyHotel"
            Width="288px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And code to fill would be:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCombo();
    }

    public void LoadCombo()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT ID, HotelName, City, " +
            "(HotelName + ' ---->(' + City + ')') AS MyHotel " +
            "FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";

        cboHotel2.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        cboHotel2.DataBind();
    }
```

And thus we get this:

[image]

However, say we have code in a button event, and we do this:

Now VERY VERY careful:

To get the drop value, you can use this:

```
        Debug.Print(cboHotel2.SelectedValue);
        Debug.Print(cboHotel2.Text);
```

BOTH will return the Value!!! (not the text!!!!).

So, I suggest avoiding the above, and you do this:

```
        Debug.Print(cboHotel2.SelectedItem.Value);
        Debug.Print(cboHotel2.SelectedItem.Text);
```

The above will now get you the "ID", and the "display text".

And also, are you setting the combo box on load to the "ID" behind, or the text value?????? (WHICH are you doing?).

You can set the PK (value) like this:

```
        cboHotel2.Text = "73";


        cboHotel2.SelectedValue = cboHotel2.Items.FindByText("Banff Aspen Lodge ---->(Golden)").Value;
```

Now that 2nd approach is VERY nasty here, since we are using a concatenated value for that 2nd display column?

Gooly gee, we must 100% match the text (and that could be hard to do!!).

As a result, I would suggest you think, you code, you use, and you write in terms of the PK value (first column) of the drop, and STAY FAR away from trying to set that combo by text in code.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand 100% what you are explaining.  I am using a stored procedure to populate the drop down value using the PK as the first column and the description as the second value.  It works, including the drop down list and the update to the database via stored proc (I am updating the database table with the PK to keep the data normalized).  So my problem is that when I retrieve the record  later, the updated table value does not show in my .aspx page, only the drop down list shows up, so it appears as if there is no data in the table in my database.  Thank you.

Comment: Hum, all good then. I would check on page load - all loading code has to be in the Is postback = false code bloc on load.

Comment: the other issue to check for? Make sure the drop down list has provisions for a blank/empty value. The database may well have a null value, but you can't shove that null into the drop down list. You have to translate to a blank, and make sure you have code to "add' a blank selection. You all need to do the reverse - if the user does not, did not select a value, then what value do you attempt to write back to database? (you have to translate blank to "null" for the database.

Comment: I changed  Text to    SelectedItem.Text and it worked!
Thanks.